# Twilio + Django - Voice message

Tags: django, twilio

Here's my requirement:

I have a text ="Thank you for your response". I want to initiate a call with a user, and when the user picks up the call, i want the text message to be turned into a voice message.

Here's what i have so far:

- I am initiating a twilio call:

`twilioClient.calls.create(to=user_number, from_=twilio_number, \
      url="https://testserver.com/call/")`

- In urls.py, i have /call/ that points to my django view module
- In view, the module looks like:

`def testTwilioCall(request):
   return HttpResponse(open('/path/call.xml').read(), content_type='application/xml')`

-call.xml looks like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Response>
      <Say voice="woman">Thank you for your response.</Say>
      <Record maxLength="20" />
    </Response>`

Here's whats happening:

- User gets a call, and the call says - "Sorry application error".

I am not sure what is going wrong. When i replace the url parameter with https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/, it works.

- I also double checked that the xml is being displayed fine from the browser.

Not sure where i am going wrong with rendering the xml.

PS: testserver is just a placeholder.

Comment: Twilio will be making a POST request to your `/call` URL, does your application respond with the XML to POST requests?

Comment: Yes, As you can see, testTwilioCall does that. It responds back with XML to the POST requests.

Comment: If you check in the Monitor section of your Twilio dashboard there will be more explanation of the error Twilio experienced. Could you post the error?

Comment: hey @philnash. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I can see the error now. Its a HTTP retrieval failure. And i know why its happening. Will work on that. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it's going to get sorted! I'll be here if you need any more help!